# How and when to use 不见不错 vs. 不见不散?

Tags: difference, expressions, colloquialisms

Could someone please explain me how and when to use these expressions? Is there any difference between the two of them? Is it something like "see you later/see you there/see you soon"?

Comment: I've no idea about what 不见不错 means, though it sounds quite poetic.

Comment: 孫楠 pairs 不见不散 w "be there or be square"- good song, good translation :)

Comment: Can you please let us know where you saw the phrase 不见不错? My guess is that it is something that Google Translate threw at you?

Comment: @MasterSparkles Do you feel that "be there or be square" indicates more of a commitment from the other person whereas 不见不散 indicates a commitment from everyone?

Comment: @Michael Lai I remember having seen this phrase written on a book, but now I guess I've probably just read wrong. Thanks for the explanation anyway. :)

Comment: @Chiara no worries. Looks like you are trying to learn a few languages at the same time... know any good sites for polyglots (or those that want to be one)?

Comment: @Michael Lai On Facebook there's a great community of polyglots where you can find people with whom you can exchange you languages; otherwise, if you search on Google, you can find many sites for language tandems and also on YouTube there are lots of polyglots showing their abilities and giving good tips for learning foreign languages. Check them out :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

不见不错 - there doesn't seem to be a reference to this phrase to be found... perhaps you could indicate where you saw this?

不见不散 - used to indicate a firm commitment to an appointment, in the sense that if we don't see [不见] each other then we will not leave/scatter [不散] (i.e. keep waiting).

- If it is to another person and you want to make sure the other person
  waits for you then it means "don't leave before I get there".
- If you are indicating that you'll be waiting for the other person
  then it means "I am not leaving until I see you".
- If it is to a group of people then it means "no one's going anywhere
  until we all get there".

Answer (score 3):

不见不错 is gobbledigook. 不见不散 means that you will in fact agree to meet someone, that you are really committed to it.

See you later is 再见 or 回头见.

Answer (score 1):

不见不散, not see not walk, "wait for me， don't leave"

不见不错 is not an everyday phrase. Maybe it is meant to mean

见不到也没事,  "If you don't see me (there) don't worry."